# JQuery script not firing on main page but same JQuery fires in separate php page variable inserted

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I have a **PHP** app  that works perfectly except for my hyperlinked `jQuery` call to another **PHP** page.  It is a dead link but it is underlined. The jQuery code is correct, because it is the same code on a separate **PHP** page that I call that uses the same logic... and it works on that embedded **PHP** page within this challenged page. Think I'm using ***PHP 5.x***.

```js
const friendReqURL = 'domain.com';
const thisRandNum = Math.random();

function deny_friend(x, a, b) {
  $.post(friendReqURL, {
      request: "denyFrd",
      reqID: x,
      id1: a,
      id2: b,
      thisWipit: thisRandNum
    },
    function(data) {
      $("#request" + x).html(data).show();
    });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<td bgcolor="#CCCCCC">
  <div align="center" class="style2">
    <span id="request' . $id2 . '">Withdraw Interest? 
 <a href="#" onclick="return false" onmousedown="javascript:deny_friend('. $requestID .','.$id1.', '.$id2.');"> Yes </a></span></div>
</td>
```

Page link is just inactive as if it isn't a hyperlink (yet it is).

Comment: I don't understand your question. Could you please explain what is the problem?? which error you got??

Comment: I duplicated the sql query of reqID: in my code... just found the duplication.  Somehow that duplication was disabling the jquery code.  Deleted it, it works now.

Comment: Then close the question please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I duplicated the sql query of reqID: in my code... just found the duplication. Somehow that duplication was disabling the jquery code. Deleted it, it works now. –
Vets
Jun 10 2019 at 1:40   Delete